# How to use dashlets in custom module SugarCE-6.5.12?

Tags: sugarcrm, dashlet

I have created a custom module, now i want to display in my module listview of Accounts and listview of Meetings. I wonder how to use dashlet to add two listview into my module. Can someone give me a clue? Excuse for my English.
Thank you very much!

Comment: See this Sugar Forums post as well http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/how-use-dashlets-custom-module-sugarce-6-5-12-a-86511/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the data is related. If there is a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, there should be subpanels with related Accounts and Meetings on the detail view of each record.

If you just want to drop in a listview for each module that isn't filtered, look at this blog post...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/05/15/howto-drop-a-listview-in-anywhere-with-the-listviewfacade/

Comment: Thank you jmertic, it works like a charm! i have tried both listview and subpanel. i wonder if i can change the width,height or position of listview/subpanel?